# How to write a Faiss index to memory?

Tags: python, swig, stringio, faiss

I want to write a `faiss` index to back it up on the cloud.
I can write it to a local file by using `faiss.write_index(filename, f)`.
However, I would rather dump it to memory to avoid unnecessary disk IO.

I tried passing in a `StringIO` or `ByteIO` stream, but I'm getting these error from the `swig` layer.

```
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'write_index'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    faiss::write_index(faiss::Index const *,char const *)
    faiss::write_index(faiss::Index const *,FILE *)
    faiss::write_index(faiss::Index const *,faiss::IOWriter *)
```

Any idea on how to `write_index` to memory?

Answer (score 3):

Found this [here](https://github.com/matsui528/faiss_tips)

```
chunk = faiss.serialize_index(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Github issues](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/issues/421)

You can use the following:

```py
faiss.write_index(index, filename)
```